# memory leak - C++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I need some help to find a memory leak in my C++ code. I try to put these lines in my constructor but it causes a memory leak because of lines 2 and 3 in the constructor:

```
Myclass::Myclass()
{
  ACE_Time_Value tm = ACE_OS::gettimeofday();

  m_obj.firstStr() = tm.sec();
  m_obj.secondStr() = tm.usec();
}
```

Here, `firstStr()` and `secondStr()` are both methods which return `std::string&` in another class.

Any suggestion what this memory leak depends on? I'm not sure if these 2 lines are the actual cause of the memory leak but Valgrind points to these two lines and I don't know how to find the leak.

Comment: The `object.method() = some_string;` syntax seems weird/counter-intuitive. Could you provide the definition of those methods ?

Comment: They simply return the protected attributes of the class and both are of type std::string.
std::string& firstStr() { return attr1;} and so on.

Comment: Are m_obj.firstStr() and secondStr() returning pointers? If so you are assigning some integral values to a copy of your pointer to the string (Assuming that tm.sec() and tm.usec() are returning longs).

Anyway i guess your problem is related to the fact that you assign the values of tm to a COPY of whatever is returned by firstStr() and secondStr() (reference to string?). Are you sure that your compiler does not complain about anything else?

Comment: Another question: Assuming again that sec() and usec() are providing integral values, have you checked if your strings contain the expected values? I cant think about a operator overload for long in std::string. If your strings contain the correct value there must be a overload somewhere, perhaps the leak happens there.

Comment: I guess Valgrind points to these lines because you assign long int to
string&. I wonder, what are you trying to achieve and what exactly happens there.

Answer (score 4):

I'm no expert on ACE but it seems unlikely that tm.sec() returns a string - far more likely it returns an integer (in fact it does - it returns a long). In that case, when you call your functions and assign to them you are essentially calling the string's assignment operator which assigns a single character (encoded in the long) to the string. This is almost certainly not what you want, but it should not cause a memory leak.

In other words, you are effectively doing this:

```
int main() {
    string s = "foobar";
    cout << s << endl;
    s = 65L;
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

which prints:

```
foobar
A
```

but does not leak memory.

Comment: Didn't know that it was valid to assign to strings like that. +1.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any memory leak detectors( and still suspectful) then the next best possible way is to overload your new and delete operator in your debug build and log all your memory allocations and deallocations. [One possible help](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/How_To_Find_Memory_Leaks.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

I think when

```
 ACE_Time_Value tm = ACE_OS::gettimeofday();
```

is called space string is allocated

and assigned to first and second string 
But when constructor is done ACE_Time_Value destructor  is called which deleted the string allocated.

But they are still referencing to First and second string. 
Hence the leak.

Trying coping the values. to prevent the leak.

Comment: ACE_Time_Value does not contain strings, and the functions called on it return longs.

Comment: Thx for a quick response but could you plz explain your solution a little bit more in details?thx.

Comment: When the scope of the constructor ends the tm made in constructor also ends. And destructor of tm is called and the end of scope. and to the times is points to also dies. 

And m_obj lives out of the scope of the constructor so, when the after the constructing of m_obj outside the cons it would point some deleted or de-referenced hence the leak.

Comment: @Neil care to elaborate, or are you just going to let that useless comment hang out there?

Comment: @Will See my first comment. And it's not useless, it indicates to the OP that this answerer does not know what he is talking about.